# Update table with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

SOLVED look below code snippet.

I have a problem with updating tables, The code shows no faults but it don't act as expected, it does not put any information in the Log Table.

some explenation, i have a table called User with a FK on LogID and a table called Log with PK on LogID so that should be correct, the Log has a column called TimesLoggedIn and one called LastLogedin. and i want to update them accordingly.

```
        User logid = db.Users.Single(p => p.UserID == loginID);
        logid.Log.LastLogedin= DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (logid.Log.TimesLoggedIn == null)
        {
            logid.Log.TimesLoggedIn = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            logid.Log.TimesLoggedIn = logid.Log.TimesLoggedIn + 1;
        }
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

had an embarrassing fault in my code, i had

```
Response.Redirect("ControlPanel");
```

placed before i ran the LINQ not after.

Comment: does the corresponding row in the table Log exist? what ORM are you using?

Comment: there is no information in the coloumns (LastLogedin and TimesLoggedIn ) but the row exist, it contains registeredTime and LogID with data in them

Comment: Why are you creating a new User in the middle of this code?  You don't seem to do anything with it.

Comment: removed it, it was trash from a try to fix. does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Entity Framework, so I might be wrong. But maybe the Log isn't loaded at all.

Try this:

```
var options = New DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Users>(x => x.Log);
db.LoadOptions = options;

// then your code:
User logid = db.Users.Single(p => p.UserID == loginID);
logid.Log.LastLogedin= DateTime.UtcNow;

....
```

Comment: Okay, I posted a different idea.